# Python-based document metadata parser?

Tags: python, parsing

Does anyone know a good parser for document metadata in python for unix like systems. In Java, [apache tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/) is great.

No com ... please :)

Thanks

Comment: Metadata and "office document" are very broad terms. What kind of files are you working with?

Comment: Do you by office documents mean documents created with Microsoft Office?

Comment: excel documents : xlrd does not provide metadata info like apache poi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hachoir_metadata works great with excel documents
http://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use Jython to use Tika.  You can call Java from Python using [JCC](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JCC/2.6).  You can find decent instructions for this [here](http://redmine.djity.net/projects/pythontika/wiki/Wiki).

When installing JCC you'll have to use one of two provided patches for setuptools, so it can build shared objects.  The c7 version worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04.

Another option would be to use the python subprocess module to call and capture the stdout of Tika.

Answer (score 1):

If you like tika, you could always use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) so you can reference tika directly.

Comment: sure was looking for a plain python package

Answer (score 1):

Tika seems like a great option. It's the only tool I've found (apart from OpenOffice in server mode) which supports old-style XLS files. I've done some work on making it easier to integrate Tika into a Python project, which you can find in [this blog post](http://blog.aptivate.org/2012/02/01/content-indexing-in-django-using-apache-tika/).