# Python:Determine file types by looking at its extension

Tags: python, file, package, file-type

I want to classify file types based on their extensions in python.Before writing it up myself i wanted to check if there is any python package which can be used for this purpose. By file type i mean to classify it as eg. Doc,ppt,pdf,tar,txt,iso etc. ideally it would take the file name as input and return its type.i am running on linux

Comment: A file's extension has nothing to do with its type.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python . You can *guess* by extension using `mimetypes`, but something like the `python-magic` (mentioned in the second answer) may be more reliable.

Comment: Not *nothing* (you hope they're related), but they are definitely not the same thing. Eg., You can totally change the extension of a `.jpg` to a `.doc`, but the type is still jpeg.

Comment: i just want to classify based on what the extension says. Not bothered about the actual content of the file. Any help now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into a document metadata parser. I have used [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) which is a java library in some of my projects. You can look at this question [Python-based document metadata parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239459/python-based-document-metadata-parser) to see how to use it in Python

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can use 'file' utillity which determine file type. So if you want you can use it and in your scripts too:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['file', 'yourfile'])
```

Comment: Command 'file' uses libmagic library, there is a 'python-magic' module that provides native interface and uses the same logic.